# Почему при формировании отчета с СКД выводится пустой отчет 1С?

Tags: 1с

Сделал отчет в виде таблицы без СКД - сделал форму отчета и макет для нее. Если открывать отчет на толстом клиенте с отладчиком, то он открывается и формируется нормально, но если без отладчика запускать предприятие через `F5`, то при формировании возникает ошибка `Не установлена схема компоновки данных`.

Создал в данном отчете СКД и в поле формы отчета выбрал мою форму, но теперь ничего не выводится. Как это можно исправить? Может я зря добавил СКД?

Comment: Выложите файл отчета